# Is there a better looking way? (int toString)

Tags: c#, tostring

Sometimes ToString looks so ugly.
 Is there something smarter to replace the ().ToString() with in the following example?

```
string value;
int i;
...

value = (1 + i).ToString();
```

Secondly, what do you prefer?

```
value = "0";
```

or

```
value = (0).ToString();
```

I know I much prefer "0" for readability, but it's on the other hand not representing the value the same way as the second. Now if there was a ToString operator of some kind...

Nitpicking, but I'm bored right now. ;)

---

**Addendum**
This is the code I was writing that caused me to ask the question above.

```
List<SelectListItem> result = new List<SelectListItem>(1 + items.Count);

result.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = string.Empty, Value = "0" });
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; ++i)
{
    result.Add(new SelectListItem { 
        Text = items[i],
        Value = (1 + i).ToString()
    });
}
```

Comment: "Ugly" is a subjective term.  What's ugly to me may be beautiful to you and vice-verrsa.  (also being nitpicky.)  The beauty (to me) of .ToString() is that it's very readable. It is so commonly used that there can be no mistaking what it means.  (For an example of the opposite, consider the ternary operator...)

Comment: There's no better word. But you are right... And I do like the ternary operator. ;)

Comment: How does `"" + (1 + i)` grab you?  :-)

Comment: @Rick Sladkey Not just plain ugly but damn ugly. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToString might be usefull for localisation -­> `(1000).ToString("N")`. Else, I don't see why you would use `(0).ToString()` instead of `"0"`.

Answer (score 4):

`().ToString()` is the most succinct way to do the first thing. Anybody familiar with how expressions work shouldn't have any trouble reading it.

And doing `(0).ToString()` is just as silly as doing `"a".ToCharArray()`. If you have a literal for the value you want, use it.

Comment: Oh... That explains it - you belong to that group of SO users that not only answer questions, but also try to discredit anyone who thinks different. I didn't see before you had answered too, but that explains your enthusiasm in commenting my answer. I only hope you find a life outside Stack Overflow, my friend... :-)

Comment: @rsenna: Oh, my life is not limited to Stack Overflow. I spend quite a bit of time on other parts of the Internet as well!

Comment: Anyway, I'm giving you a +1. It seems to be important to you.

Comment: @rsenna: What a nice thing of you to do (...)

Answer (score 3):

In fact I always use `Convert.ToString(i + 1)`, instead of the `(i + 1).ToString()`. The former is null-safe.

And I would never use `value = (0).ToString()`!

**Edit**

Since I'm really fond of that solution, I'll try to defend it better:

Pros:

1. It is pretty common idiom, not particularly hard to read.
2. It works with both value and reference types - so it increases code cohesion, since all conversions look exactly the same.
3. Can be used in place of most casts and conversions.
4. It is null-safe - which is very useful when dealing with DAO classes or UI bindings, for instance.

Cons:

1. It is slower than casts (but not necessarily slower than other kinds of conversions, like `object.ToString()`).
2. May hide null reference exceptions - this is usually not recommended in core, business classes (but again, one seldom uses text to numeric conversions in that kind of code).

Comment: I would only use "null-safe" code if nulls are expected. An unexpected null *should* result in an exception because it means there's something wrong.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: I disagree. A *valid* null "value" in a type T can be represented as a null string, if there is a valid conversion from T to string, period. That is not an error *per se*. If a null value is *invalid*, according to some arbitrary business rule, then you should implement some explicit validation in order to avoid it.

Comment: @rsenna: If you accept a null string as a null value, then it's not an unexpected null. Explicitly validating things each and every time you access them results in complicated and hard to read code. Check for nulls where they might occur, and trust that non-nulls won't magically turn into nulls elsewhere. Just to make it clear, I was reacting to the poster saying that he *always* uses a null-safe way, whether he expects nulls or not.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: 1) The question is highly *subjective* - **I** do that way, and if you don't, so be it. I said "**I** always use", I'm not saying you should do the same. 2) I don't think `Convert.ToString()` is "hard to read code" - in fact it is a pretty common idiom. 3) There is no magic involved - when you use the `Convert` class, nulls keep being nulls - you just avoid `NullReferenceException`s. That being said, I really am not sure what exactly is your problem with my answer.

Comment: @rsenna: Oh, I don't have any problem with your particular answer, just the tendency of some people to write overly-defensive code which just ends up being hard to read.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: Sorry, in fact I find *your* comments to be "overly-defensive", and I'm not even sure what exactly you are trying to defend. In spite of that, I have edited my answer; let me know if it makes you a little bit less upset. :-P

Comment: Gee, you didn't have to go that far...

Comment: It is null-safe but integers are value types and therefore can't be null

Answer (score 1):

If you need to represent a `0` as an integer, don't use a string, use an integer.

As for converting the result of a calculation to a string:

```
var res = string.Format("{0}", i + 1);
```

You don't need to use `()` with a literal integer - `0.ToString()` works.

Comment: In my case SelectListItem.Value is a string wether I like it or not. :)

Comment: @Carl - Now, where does that appear in your question? I must have missed it...

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment?

Comment: Nowhere. The question was just open, but I happened to write an extension method returning List<SelectListItem> at the moment.

Comment: `string.Format` is almost guaranteed to operate more slowly than `int.ToString`, given that `int.ToString` must be called in `string.Format`. Therefore I wouldn't recommend this - nevermind the fact that it is an extreme overdesign choice that just looks plain overcomplicated for the task at hand.

Comment: @Oded I was the downvoter, sometimes it takes a bit to comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ugly is such an ugly word.  For example, to me, completely subjective, but your style of writing `1 + i` is just plain wrong.  Mathematicians never say *1+n*, they say *n+1*.  But that's just my preference.  Things that are matters of opinion are hard to answer technically.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the 1 + i style issue. I think it comes from always putting constants in front of ==. It must somehow has expanded on it's own to include other operators in my head.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using `string.Format("{0}", 1 + i)`.

I'd rather go with `"0"`, why to call an extra method?

Comment: +1 i would have done exactly the same